# Finding inequivalent representations in a given group

Tags: representation-theory

I am studying characters of representations and how number of conjugacy classes is same as the number of inequivalent representations in a group. However, my question is, how do we actually find all the inequivalent representations in a given group, rather than just know how many of them there are? Are there some basic algorithms?

Comment: They're all present as subrepresentations of the regular representation.  One can also induce from representations of subgroups (see wiki: induced representation).

Comment: If you have a faithful representation, you can obtain all finite dimensional irreducibles by looking inside the tensor powers of the faithful representation.